# Copying a project for Sidekick

Tags: project, nativescript

When I copy a project, I give the project folder a new name particularly if I want maintain the old version and create a new version with additional features. The problem with this is the compiled project takes the name from the folder name of the project which is a pain. For example if the initial is folder is myproject and I create a new folder myprojectwithfeatures, the file once installed becomes myprojectwithfeatures and not myproject. In sidekick, the project name/App name cannot be changed it is greyed out.

Is it possible to change the App Name to maintain the name across versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy a project, I use the `tns create` command thusly:

```
tns create mynewapp --appid domain.mynewapp --template <path to>/myoldapp/app
```

This seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use SideKick but you can always update the project name to anything by modifying `CFBundleDisplayName` entry in `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist` and `android:label="YourAppName"` attribute of `application` tag in `App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1377).

Comment: Yes thanks for that but seems an unnecessary method when it would be so easy to change it within Sidekick considering how this tool is designed to be used.

Comment: As I already said, I'm not a Sidekick user. So I'm not sure whether they support updating these values form Sidekick GUI.